# I am having a party at 7 PM

Tags: present-continuous

Is it OK to specify the time when the party starts yet to use the present continuous?

**I am having a party at 7 PM.**

Why I think it might be wrong is because 7 PM refers to a schedule. So, why not the present simple?

Comment: Asking if something is correct is considered proof-reading and off-topic here. Your question may be voted to be closed unless you can update it. Did you do some research? Can you included that in your question? Is there a reason why you think it might be wrong?

Comment: I have a party at 7 pm **every Friday**. That's why not.

Comment: What does EVERY FRIDAY have to do with my example? I can put TODAY instead of every Friday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Why not?" is the wrong question.

Both tenses are fine. You can use present simple if you want.

If you want to describe the party as an event on your schedule, then use present simple. If you want to describe it as a definite future plan that you have, use present continuous.

Present continuous also carries the meaning that you are the organizer because it's the action verb "have a party", which means, "throw a party".

Present simple doesn't specify if you're organizing the party or not because "have" with present simple with the function a schedule always indicates the event on the schedule, not an action, so this can only mean, "There is a party on my schedule at 7 pm", which you mighty be organizing or not.

Comment: What if I am the organizer of the party? Both tenses are OK or only the continuous?

Comment: @user1425 I've added that info to my answer. Lemme know if that helps